# Surround CSV lines with double quotes/ create custom main method

Tags: java, csv, parsing, escaping, double-quotes

I have to take a CSVReader IBM created and make changes that fit my requirements. I am new to java and not sure how to do any except for #1, my requirements are:

1. take the CSV through the command line
2. add a main method
3. surround each line with double quotes
4. output a new CSV

Ex. Input
Jordan, Michael, J, ", 23
Ex. Output
"Jordan, Michael, J, "", 23"

Background information: this program will be added into a shell script, the functionality is being added because the csv is corrupted if a single double quote is entered

Here is the code:

```
package Scripts;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.Reader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class CSVReader 
{
    private BufferedReader br;
    private boolean hasNext = true;
    private static char separator = ' ';
    private static char quotechar = ' '; 

    public static final char DEFAULT_SEPARATOR = ',';
    public static final char DEFAULT_QUOTE_CHARACTER = '"';

    public static void main(final String[] args) throws IOException {
    final String csvFile = args[0];
    final ArrayList<String[]> allElements = new ArrayList<String[]>();
    final CSVReader csvReader = new CSVReader(br, separator, quotechar, csvFile);
    csvTransformer.readAll();
    csvTransformer.close();
}

    public CSVReader(final Reader reader) throws FileNotFoundException {
        this(reader, DEFAULT_SEPARATOR);
    }

    public CSVReader(final Reader reader, final char separator) throws FileNotFoundException {
        this(reader, separator, DEFAULT_QUOTE_CHARACTER, null);
    }
    public CSVReader(final Reader reader, final char separator, final char quotechar, final String csvFile) throws FileNotFoundException {
        CSVTransformer.br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(csvFile));
        this.separator = separator;
        this.quotechar = quotechar;
    }


/**
 * Reads the entire file into a List with each element being a String[] of tokens.
 * 
 * return a List of String[], with each String[] representing a line of the file.
 */
    public List readAll() throws IOException 
    {
        List allElements = new ArrayList();
        while (hasNext) 
        {
            String[] nextLineAsTokens = readNext();
            if (nextLineAsTokens != null) 
                allElements.add(nextLineAsTokens);
        }
        return allElements;
    }

/**
 * Reads the next line from the buffer and converts to a string array.
 * 
 * return a string array with each comma-separated element as a separate entry.
 */
    public String[] readNext() throws IOException {
        String nextLine = getNextLine();
        return hasNext ? parseLine(nextLine) : null;
    }

/**
 * Reads the next line from the file.
 * 
 * return the next line from the file without trailing newline
 */
    private String getNextLine() throws IOException {
        String nextLine = br.readLine();
        if (nextLine == null) {
            hasNext = false;
        }
        return hasNext ? nextLine : null;
    }

/**
 * Parses an incoming String and returns an array of elements.
 * 
 * @param nextLine
 *            the string to parse
 * @return the comma-tokenized list of elements, or null if nextLine is null
 * @throws IOException if bad things happen during the read
 */
    private String[] parseLine(String nextLine) throws IOException {
        if (nextLine == null) {
            return null;
        }
        List tokensOnThisLine = new ArrayList();
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
        boolean inQuotes = false;
        do {
            if (inQuotes) {
            // continuing a quoted section, reappend newline
                sb.append("\n");
                nextLine = getNextLine();
                if (nextLine == null)
                break;
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < nextLine.length(); i++) {
                char c = nextLine.charAt(i);
                if (c == quotechar) {
                // this gets complex... the quote may end a quoted block, or escape another quote.
                // do a 1-char lookahead:
                if(inQuotes)  // we are in quotes, therefore there can be escaped quotes in here.
                        && nextLine.length() > (i+1)  // there is indeed another character to check.
                        && nextLine.charAt(i+1) == quotechar )
                    { // ..and that char. is a quote also.
                    // we have two quote chars in a row == one quote char, so consume them both and
                    // put one on the token. we do *not* exit the quoted text.
                        sb.append(nextLine.charAt(i+1));
                        i++;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        inQuotes = !inQuotes;
                    }
                }
                else if (c == separator && !inQuotes) {
                    tokensOnThisLine.add(sb.toString());
                    sb = new StringBuffer(); // start work on next token
                }
                else {
                    sb.append(c);
                }
            }
        } while (inQuotes);
        tokensOnThisLine.add(sb.toString());
        return (String[]) tokensOnThisLine.toArray(new String[0]);
    }

    public void close() throws IOException {
        br.close();
    }
}
on
```

Answer (score 1):

If your only need is about escaping double quotes, a simple way to do it is not considering the CSV file as a CSV but as a simple text file.

first thing first: the main method in Java is quite simple. use this declaration:

```
public static void main(String... args){
    //do your stuff
    // args is a String array containing parameters passed to your script, like your file. to get the first param, use args[0] , for the second it's args[1] ...
}
```

the main method will be automatically used by java if one is found in the called java class.

important point: main method MUST be public static and returning nothing
as you can see here : [Java spec, chapter 12](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.1.4)

about your need, read each line from the file and replace it with the result of this function in a new file:

```
/**
 * 
 * replace quotes in a line and append/prepend quotes to the line and return it
 * 
 */
private static String correctQuotesInLine(String nextLine) {
    if (nextLine == null) {
        return null;
    }

    //replace any single " in line
    String result = nextLine.replaceAll("\"", "\"\"");
    //prepend and append line with quotes
     result = "\"" + result + "\"";


    return result;
}
```

to write your resulting file, you can use those informations :

[how to write files line by line using java](http://www.programcreek.com/2011/03/java-write-to-a-file-code-example/)

Comment: My apologies for not being clear, I was confused about the main method, because I'm given 3 different constructors, and was unclear about which one to use, and when I should be passing values to them in main.

Comment: I'm not sure about what you ask. You can use any of existing constructor depending on what you need. The first constructor will create a CSVReader with défaut separator, and défaut quotechar. If you want to change it, use the third one and specify tour separator/quotechar as param. Maybe try to write a bit of code and post it here. It will be easier to understand your need.

Comment: Basically, "this" represents  your instance. It's not mandatory, but avoid  confusion when you set variables inside consrructor. About constructors, the "réal" one is the third here. Second one call the third with a default quotechar parameter. Same  about the first one which call the second (which call the third) with a default separator parameter. Then the constructor simply  set variables.

Comment: Okay. From that info, I set my BufferedReader inside of the 3rd constructor and am now getting a NullPointerException. Any ideas on how to pass that file, it must come from the command line.

Comment: I would pass the path as parameter to your main method  then retrieve the file from there

Comment: The nullpointerexception  comes  from this line : 
CSVTransformer.br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(csvFile)); 
csvFile is never  initialised. Follow the code flow, you are using the first constructor in the main method  which make  a call to the second constructor which make a call to the third constructor with a null as csvFile parameter. It would be easier to directly call the third constructor with args[0] as csvFile param

Comment: Gotcha! I updated the code that way, and no exceptions! Are you understanding the functionality of the for loop inside of the parseLine method? I'm reading the comments, but it does seem like it is complete.

Comment: Hardly.. And i'm on a phone... It's a hard to read code. It seems to look for double quotes and "block quoted" (on different lines) and return a list of string tokens representing the line

Answer (score 0):

Here is the full code, with all requirements met:

```
package Scripts;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.Reader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class CSVReader {

private static BufferedReader br;
private static BufferedWriter writer;
private static FileWriter fileWriter;
private boolean hasNext = true;
private static char separator = ' ';
private static char quotechar = ' ';
static List<String[]> allElements;

public static final char DEFAULT_SEPARATOR = ',';
public static final char DEFAULT_QUOTE_CHARACTER = '"';

public static void main(final String[] args) throws IOException {
    final String csvFile = args[0];
    final File newCSV = new File("newCSV.csv");
    final CSVReader csvTransformer = new CSVReader(br, separator, quotechar, csvFile, newCSV);
    csvTransformer.readAll();
    csvTransformer.close();
}

public CSVReader(final Reader reader) throws IOException {
    this(reader, DEFAULT_SEPARATOR);
}

public CSVReader(final Reader reader, final char separator) throws IOException {
    this(reader, separator, DEFAULT_QUOTE_CHARACTER, null, null);
}

public CSVReader(final Reader reader, final char separator, final char quotechar, final String csvFile,
        final File newCSV) throws IOException {
    CSVReader.br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(csvFile));
    CSVReader.separator = separator;
    CSVReader.quotechar = quotechar;
    CSVReader.fileWriter = new FileWriter(newCSV.getAbsoluteFile());
    CSVReader.writer = new BufferedWriter(fileWriter);
}

/**
 * Reads the entire file into a List with each element being a String[] of tokens.
 *
 * return a List of String[], with each String[] representing a line of the file.
 */

public List<String[]> readAll() throws IOException {
    final List<String[]> allElements = new ArrayList<String[]>();
    while (hasNext) {
        final String[] nextLineAsTokens = readNext();
        if (nextLineAsTokens != null) {
            allElements.add(nextLineAsTokens);
        }
    }
    return allElements;
}

/**
 * Reads the next line from the buffer and converts to a string array.
 *
 * return a string array with each comma-separated element as a separate entry.
 */

public String[] readNext() throws IOException {
    final String nextLine = getNextLine();
    return hasNext ? parseLine(nextLine) : null;
}

/**
 * Reads the next line from the file.
 *
 * return the next line from the file without trailing newline
 */

private String getNextLine() throws IOException {
    final String nextLine = br.readLine();
    if (nextLine == null) {
        hasNext = false;
    }
    return hasNext ? nextLine : null;
}

/**
 * Parses an incoming String and returns an array of elements & adds results to CSV.
 *
 * @param nextLine
 *            the string to parse
 * @return the comma-tokenized list of elements, or null if nextLine is null
 * @throws IOException
 *             if bad things happen during the read
 */

private String[] parseLine(final String nextLine) throws IOException {

    if (nextLine == null) {
        return null;
    }
    final List<String> tokensOnThisLine = new ArrayList<String>();
    String result = nextLine.replaceAll("\"", "\"\"");
    result = "\"" + result + "\"";
    tokensOnThisLine.add(result.toString());
    writer.write(result);
    writer.write("\n");
    return tokensOnThisLine.toArray(new String[0]);
}

public void close() throws IOException {
    br.close();
    writer.close();
}
} // end
```